# ParseException: No property or field '???' exists in type 'DynamicClass' when using GroupBy and Select

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dynamic, poco, dynamic-class

I'm using EntityFramework together with [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) and I've defined Employee POCO class as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using this code to do a GroupBy the Country Name:

```
var query = Employees.Include(e => e.Company).Include(e => e.Country);  
var groupByQuery = query.GroupBy("new (Country.Code as GroupByField)", "new (it AS XEmployee, it.Company AS XCompany, it.Country AS XCountry)");
var selectQuery = groupByQuery.Select("new (Key.GroupByField, it as Grouping)");
var grouping = selectQuery.Select("it.Grouping") as IQueryable<IGrouping<DynamicClass, DynamicClass>>;
var objects = grouping.First().AsQueryable() as IQueryable<object>;

// This line gives me : ParseException: No property or field 'XEmployee' exists in type 'DynamicClass'
var employees = objects.Select("it.XEmployee");
```

It's very strange because when I dump all the properties from the DynamicClass, the XEmployee is a valid public property ?

```
var firstObject = objects.First();
firstObject.GetType().GetProperties().Dump();
```

Shows
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an extension method which gets a property from an object and casts this to the required type.

See this code for the extension method "Select"

```
public static class DynamicQueryableExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<TEntity> Select<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<object> source, string propertyName)
   {
       return source.Select(x => GetPropertyValue<TEntity>(x, propertyName));
   }

   private static T GetPropertyValue<T>(object self, string propertyName)
   {
       var type = self.GetType();
       var propInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

       try
       {
           return propInfo != null ? (T)propInfo.GetValue(self, null) : default(T);
       }
       catch
       {
           return default(T);
       }
   }
}
```

The code is used as follows:

```
// This line will just work fine.
var employees = objects.Select<Employee>("XEmployee");
employees.Dump();
```

For a working example, see my [KendoGridBinderEx](https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx) project on github.